# Programming with N-tier

Tags: .net, architecture, c#-4.0

What are the general guideline today for structuring a 3-tier application in Visual Studio 2010 with C#?

1. Create blank Solution
2. Create a class library to hold data sets
3. Create a class library to hold data
   entity
4. Create a class library to hold the
   business logic
5. Create a class library to hold user
   interface (WPF or windows forms)

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

There a lot of right ways, and based on the application it may be perfect or not good.
Your structure seams good.
But you may need to check a book like this:
[patterns & practices Application Architecture Guide 2.0](http://apparchguide.codeplex.com/)